# POST url encoded form to Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating a webhook to receive notifications from a 3rd-party service, they sent the data in the body of a POST with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

But it generates the same error:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'name\': was expecting \'null\', \'true\', \'false\' or NaN\n at [Source: [B@456fe137; line: 1, column: 6]"}
```

I could reproduce the error with the following curl call:

```
% curl -v -X POST -d 'name=Ignacio&city=Tehuixtla' https://rl9b6lh8gk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/mandrillListener
*   Trying 54.230.227.63...
* Connected to rl9b6lh8gk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (54.230.227.63) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> POST /prod/mandrillListener HTTP/1.1
> Host: rl9b6lh8gk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 27
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 27 out of 27 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 180
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 12:29:40 GMT
< x-amzn-RequestId: cd4d9232-c5ba-11e5-a158-b9b39f0b0599
< X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 1915b8b49d2fbff532431a79650103eb.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: cxU2_b5DzIw4M_n3hJBFXTu9AVRBL3GpbQqUId9IxgS004DfLYqYmg==
<
* Connection #0 to host rl9b6lh8gk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'name\': was expecting \'null\', \'true\', \'false\' or NaN\n at [Source: [B@d92973b; line: 1, column: 6]"}
```

If I wrap the body with double-quotes it works fine:

```
% curl -v -X POST -d '"name=Ignacio&city=Tehuixtla"' https://rl9b6lh8gk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/mandrillListener
*   Trying 54.230.227.19...
* Connected to rl9b6lh8gk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (54.230.227.19) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> POST /prod/mandrillListener HTTP/1.1
> Host: rl9b6lh8gk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 29
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 6
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 12:33:20 GMT
< x-amzn-RequestId: 50610606-c5bb-11e5-b140-5d837ffe26ed
< X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 a670cda0e28541e40881b95b60c672b7.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: mCLKL4eOnpUMd15IXQZw0RStJHw9Vdf3ivdCl37dcmno2JFOfxw0Vg==
<
* Connection #0 to host rl9b6lh8gk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
"true"%
```

The lamba has only one line:

```
context.succeed('true');
```

How can I make the api gateway do not treat the body as json?

I tried the documentation about template mapping with no success, I even tried to convert it to a static template, with no variables at all! In all cases the error happens before getting to my code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to set mapping template as following:

```
{
  "body" : $input.json('$')
}
```

This would convert you string into json and pass to lambda.

From amazon [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html):
`$input.json(x)` function evaluates a JSONPath expression and returns the results as a JSON string.

Comment: As @hayduke replied, it is important to Deploy the API after this change to see it applied.

Comment: @jfredys +1 +1 +1 +1 I was completely missing the deployment after changing the mapping template. Wasted two days.

Comment: This is not a working solution. First of all, there is no mention of where in AWS you go to change "body mapping template". Secondly, when I add this to my project I get the response, `{"statusCode":502,"body":"","headers":{}}` and errors in cloudwatch, `ERROR: aws-serverless-express connection error` and `Error: socket hang up`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not entirely related, but if you are new to Amazon API Gateway, one additional step I did not know was required was to (re) *deploy* your API after adding the mapping template as others have suggested (in the case you had previously deployed your API). This cost me a bunch of debugging time as I did not understand why I was continuing to get this error even after making the suggestions posted here.

If using the AWS Console,

- navigate to any pane within your API
- Select Actions menu at the top
- Select Deploy API from the menu, choose the relevant stage and confirm

Comment: How will you get the url for checking if you didn't deploy

Comment: I think my comment was only relevant if you had previously deployed a version of your API (and thus had a URL). It's necessary to re-deploy. Perhaps that would be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

The mapping template to make form data work is pretty complicated. Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/ryanray/668022ad2432e38493df

Also, you can see this post I wrote that has an example of how to integrate with Slack(their hooks send a POST as form data to API Gateway): http://www.ryanray.me/serverless-slack-integrations

Comment: This is the only template that worked for me when I was sending an email address in the form.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the **API Gateway**, select the POST method for your resource, select **Integration Request** and create a new **Mapping Template** for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
#set($body = $input.path('$'))
#set($jsonString = $util.urlencode($body))
#set($json = $util.parsejson($jsonString))

{
  "body" : $json,
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply pass the url encoded string:

```
#set($body = $input.path('$'))
{
  "body" : "$body",
}
```

and url decode and parse the JSON in your lambda.