# Test of API Gateway POST with Content-Type x-www-form-urlencoded returns 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to configure an API Gateway endpoint that receives an HTTP POST with a URL-encoded body.  I simply want to convert the body to JSON and send it to SQS.

I cannot get the POST method test in the API Gateway console to succeed: it always results in **415 - Unsupported Media Type**.

My POST "Integration Request" block is configured for "AWS Service" with SQS:

[image: Integration Request]

For Mapping Templates, I have added the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type with a corresponding template:

[image: Mapping Template]

Finally, I configured my test with header `Content-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded` and provided a simple Request Body `message=This%20is%20the%20message`:

[image: POST Method Test]

Unfortunately, the result is always "**Unsupported Media Type**".   I cannot figure out why this is failing.  The Mapping Template should be matching the Content-Type and applying the template.

Any suggestions what might be wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: The second to last line about execution failing makes it sound like an issue with your template / transform, rather than just the content type?

Comment: @David that's a good thought.   I just changed the template to have fixed JSON and I'm still getting the error.    `{ "body": "this is the body" }`

Comment: Only other thing I noticed is the red `X` icon by your request body. Does it have some sort of tooltip / info? I wonder if it doesn't play nice with form url encoded? Are you able to test with a blank request body just to see what  happens, or maybe XML and add the template for it?

Comment: One other thing you could also test is setting the request body passthrough setting to "when no template matches found". Then if you no longer receive the 415, it will at least have verified that template matching is 100% the source of error - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html

Comment: @David good suggestions.  The red X indicates an invalid body, however the only thing that satisfies the body (removes the red X) is JSON.    I did change the passthrough to "when no template matches found" and the request was successful, so it does appear template matching is the issue.

Comment: Wondering if this might be the cause? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37999238/196033

Sounds like you have to re-deploy the API after adding the template for it to take effect (even in testing tool?)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem. For some reason, I have to define a mapping template for "application/json" even though I want to send  application/x-www-form-urlencoded. When I send  application/x-www-form-urlencoded, it seems to pick the application/json mapping template. My endpoint is a mock endpoint, so in the end it works the way I expect but YMMV if you need to process the request payload somehow.